# How do I approach this homogeneous ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following ODE:

$(t^2-1) h''(t)+2t h'(t) + (\cfrac{a}{\sqrt{b-2ct}}+d)h(t)=0$

With $a=0$, the ODE is essentially Legendre's differential equation, but of course $a\neq0$ in my case.  With the addition of the $a/\sqrt{b-2ct}$ term, none of the solution techniques I am familiar with have proven useful.  The constants $a$, $b$, and $c$ are all greater than zero, $d$ may be negative, and $-1\leq t\leq 1$.  You may assume $b-2ct> 0$.